# Deployment error System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex, unit-test, query, list, indexing

I have the following apex code where I do a soql. In my developer sandbox my testclass gives me 100% coverage. When I deploy this to production I get the error:

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

My error is on the line with: AFAS_ID__c= afas1[0].id

```
if(acc[x].BUMA_Achtergrondmuziek__c !='N.v.t.'){  
                List <AFAS_Artikel__c> afas1= [SELECT id, AFAS_Code__c   FROM AFAS_Artikel__c WHERE AFAS_Code__c  = : acc[x].BUMA_Achtergrondmuziek__c LIMIT 1];
            Factuurregel__c fa =new Factuurregel__c(Organisatie__c=acc[x].id, Debiteur__c = acc[x].Debiteurennummer__c ,
                                                    Aantal__c = 1 
                                                    ,  AFAS_ID__c= afas1[0].id
                                                    , Factuurdatum__c= date.today(),Referentie__c = ''+ System.Today().year());
           }
```

Comment: afas1 is likely empty.

Comment: Is your test running in "see all data" mode? If so that'd explain the difference between environments. In which case, create some sample data in the unit test instead of relying on org data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to look first if your list is empty. sth like this

```
if(acc.size() > 1 && acc[x].BUMA_Achtergrondmuziek__c !='N.v.t.'){

      List <AFAS_Artikel__c> afas1= [SELECT id, AFAS_Code__c   FROM AFAS_Artikel__c WHERE AFAS_Code__c  = : acc[x].BUMA_Achtergrondmuziek__c LIMIT 1];
       if (afas1.size() > 1) {
             Factuurregel__c fa =new Factuurregel__c(Organisatie__c=acc[x].id, Debiteur__c = acc[x].Debiteurennummer__c ,
                                                Aantal__c = 1 
                                                ,  AFAS_ID__c= afas1[0].id
                                                , Factuurdatum__c= date.today(),Referentie__c = ''+ System.Today().year());}}
```

This way you are making sure, that you will not try to get an element from any empty list.